# Does Microsoft Release Management 2013 needs sysadmin access?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, release-management, ms-release-management

Getting the below error during password change of account in RM 2013 configuration,

" User XXX should be a sysadmin for SQL Server Instance YYY to perform the database configuration"

I checked with our DBA he has removed sysadmin access for the particular user.

[image]

Is there a way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve the issue is to give the user the stated required level of permission.

Comment: thanks Daniel for the inputs. But as per company policy DBA guy has restricted access for sysadmin. Is there any other way to tackle this

Comment: still looking out a way to solve this issues. any help/ideas is appreciated.

Comment: Give the user the required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the prompt information, you have to add the appropriate permissions to continue the configuration.

Generally speaking, there's no way to bypass the required  permissions. If you could, what's the need of setting the permissions?